# Find $g(x)$ from the following condition: ${g(x)}=(\int_{0}^{1}{e}^{x+t}{g(t)}dt)+x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, differential, leibniz-integral-rule

Find $g(x)$ from the following condition: $${g(x)}=\left(\int_{0}^{1}{e}^{x+t}{g(t)}dt\right)+x$$ I have tried to solve it by applying Newton-Leibnitz formula and solving the linear differential equation with the help of integrating factor, but I am getting $g(x)$ as $1+x$, it does not satisfy the original equation,
Please tell me where I have gone wrong and suggest a better approach to this question.

Comment: Did you take $e^x$ out of the integrand? Show how your method, it can be confusing

Comment: Yes I have taken it out and applied product rule

Comment: Are the bounds on the integral correct or should there be some dependency on $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest another approach. We know:
\begin{equation}
{g(x)}=\left(\int_{0}^{1}{e}^{t}{g(t)}dt\right){e}^{x}+x
=C{e}^{x}+x,
\end{equation}
where $C=\int_{0}^{1}{e}^{t}{g(t)}dt$. We only need to discover the value of $C$. But:
\begin{equation}
C=\int_{0}^{1}{e}^{x}{g(x)}dx
=\int_{0}^{1}(C{e}^{2x}+xe^x)dx
=C\int_{0}^{1}{e}^{2x}dx+\int_{0}^{1}xe^xdx
\end{equation}
Therefore:
\begin{equation}
C\left(1-\int_{0}^{1}{e}^{2x}dx\right)=\int_{0}^{1}xe^xdx
\end{equation}
which can be easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

Write $h(x)=g(x)-x$. Solve the differential equation
$$h(x)=e^x\int_0^1e^t(h(t)+t)dt$$
by integrating
$\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}=1.$

the soulotion to the equation is $h(x)=e^{x+c}$ for some constant $c$. To find the constant solve the equation
$$e^{x+c}=e^x\int_0^1e^t(e^{t+c}+t)dt$$